# Strong wood coating?

Tags: wood, polyurethane, wood-finishing

I made a magnetic knife holder out of wood and coated with Arm-r-Seal oil urethane but after 3 days of curing it seems it'll get beat up too fast. What's the strongest I could use?

Is this a good application for epoxy? I haven't worked with it before due to price.

If I do use epoxy, how well does the old finish need to be cleaned off?

edit: epoxy might not be food-safe enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two part polyurethane is the way to go, Its food safe when hard, and the active hardener makes a really good hard surface.

I also like the finish that these products add to the surface, and you typically could add about three layers to make it really bullet-proof.

The stuff is a little bit expensive, but well worth the money!.